# What's the best approach to take when modifying a constraint class provided by the grails framework

Tags: grails, groovy, constraints, overriding, grails-orm

The class `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.CreditCardConstraint` in `grails-2.4.5` utilizes the deprecated version of `CreditCardValidator` from the `org.apache.commons.validator` package.

I wish to modify it to use the non-deprecated version of `CreditCardValidator` from the `org.apache.commons.validator.routines` package.

I cannot upgrade my version of grails at this time.

What’s the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I guess below code is what you are looking for? Remember to define customType.

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.CreditCardValidator

class MyDomainOrCommand {

    String creditCard
    ...

    static constraints = {

            creditCard nullable: false, validate: { value, object ->
                CreditCardValidator v = new CreditCardValidator(CreditCardValidator.NONE);
                v.addAllowedCardType(customType);

                if(!v.isValid(value)) {
                    return 'creditCard.invalid'
                }
                return true
            }
    }
    ...
}
```